# Continuous with f(x,x)

Tags: limits, continuity

I need to extend the function so that it's get continuous at (1,1).
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x^2-y^2}$$

I've done this $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{(x-y)(1)}{(x-y)(x+y)}\Rightarrow\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{1}{x+y}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Facit says $$f(x,x)=\frac{1}{2x}, (x,x)\neq0$$

What do the double x mean ($f(x,x)$) and where does this x come from ($\frac{1}{2x}$)?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I'm not sure what his notation means and I suspect the extraneous $x$ may be a typo, but your solution is correct.

Comment: What is Facit exactly ?

Comment: Facit:$f(x,x)=\frac{1}{2x}$ makes $f$ continuous at $(x,x)\ for\ x\neq0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not defined on for $x=y$.

We have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,a)}\frac {x-y}{x^2-y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,a)}\frac 1{x+y}=\frac 1 {2a}$$

Therefore we should define $f(x,x)=\dfrac1{2x}$.

Here $f(x,x)$ is the value of the function when the two arguments are the same.

e.g. for $g(x,y) = xy$, $g(x,x)=x^2$.